# Powershell: AsyncCallback Events using Hidlibrary

Tags: powershell, dll, hid, asynccallback

I need some help implementing asynchronous events in Powershell.

As a testbed for a larger HID project I want to use Powershell to read the data from a usb panic button that I got off amazon.  The perfect solution would implement the data callback as an event that could then be registered using Register-ObjectEvent.

My current approach is to use the [Hidlibrary](https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary) library.  I am having difficulty invoking both the Read() or ReadReport() methods.  They do not appear to be typical asynccallbacks and the standard solution of using [New-ScriptBlockCallback](http://poshcode.org/1382) does not work.

What I have so far that works and allows me to pull a readhandle.

```
Add-Type -Path .\Projects\UsbPanicButton\HidLibrary.dll
$device = [HidLibrary.HidDevices]::GetDevice('\\?\hid#vid_1130&pid_0202&mi_00#7&29add023&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}')
$device.OpenDevice()
```

This does not work. (Cannot find an overload)

```
$device.ReadReport((New-ScriptBlockCallback {Write-host "HI"}))
```

How can I convert the ReadReport method into an event that can be registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ReadReport method signature:

```
public delegate void ReadReportCallback(HidReport report);
```

Isn't a fit for New-ScriptBlockCallback. It works with methods taking an AsyncCallback parameter.  *IF* you know the callback is called on the creating thread during the ReadReport method call you can use:

```
$device.ReadReport({param($hidReport) $hidReport.ReadStatus })
```

If it is called back on a different thread, try this modified version of the New-ScriptBlockCallback function:

```
function New-ScriptBlockCallback {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [scriptblock]$Callback
    )

    if (-not ("CallbackEventBridge" -as [type])) {
        Add-Type @"
            using System;
            using HidLibrary;

            public sealed class CallbackEventBridge
            {
                public event HidDevice.ReadReportCallback CallbackComplete = delegate { };

                private CallbackEventBridge() {}

                private void CallbackInternal(HidReport report)
                {
                    CallbackComplete(report);
                }

                public HidDevice.ReadReportCallback Callback
                {
                    get { return new HidDevice.ReadReportCallback(CallbackInternal); }
                }

                public static CallbackEventBridge Create()
                {
                    return new CallbackEventBridge();
                }
            }
"@
    }
    $bridge = [callbackeventbridge]::create()
    Register-ObjectEvent -input $bridge -EventName callbackcomplete -action $callback -messagedata $args > $null
    $bridge.callback
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keith!  I was not able to get the second method to work.  Is this how I call ReadReport?  `$device.ReadReport({New-ScriptBlockCallback {Write-Host "HI"}})`  It crashes powershell.

Comment: You would call it like so: `$device.ReadReport((new-scriptblock {Write-Host "hi"}))`.